# Linking Page data to Filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, geo

I have a set of geographic data tied to date. I want to show change in this geographic data over time. In my tableau sheet, I added the Date field as a "Page" so that I have a play button, but the measures don't change over time. When I press the play button on the Page window, it looks like it's cycling through dates, but it just shows the same values on screen the whole time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag date in pages(that will be change frequently)

[image]

Now select toggle for animation speed

[image]

Now select loop playback from option

[image]

Finally click on revers or forward play to visualize your flow
[image]